# (Composer) Как установить необходимые зависимости для Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, composer

Есть сайт, заказчик просит меня добавить слайдер в одну из страниц, но я попросту не могу получить доступ к странице из-за ошибок. Что мне нужно прописать в консоле или как мне игноируя ошибки, просто получить статическую страницу?

```
C:\OpenServer\domains\expressnails.ru>composer install

Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Verifying lock file contents can be installed on current platform.
Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. It is recommended that you run `composer update` or `composer update <package name>`.
Your lock file does not contain a compatible set of packages. Please run composer update.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires php ^7.2 but your php version (8.0.8) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 2
    - mongodb/mongodb is locked to version 1.8.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - mongodb/mongodb 1.8.0 requires ext-mongodb ^1.8.1 -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's mongodb extension.
  Problem 3
    - paragonie/random_compat is locked to version v9.99.99 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - paragonie/random_compat v9.99.99 requires php ^7 -> your php version (8.0.8) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 4
    - fzaninotto/faker is locked to version v1.9.2 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - fzaninotto/faker v1.9.2 requires php ^5.3.3 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.8) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 5
    - paragonie/random_compat v9.99.99 requires php ^7 -> your php version (8.0.8) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - ramsey/uuid 3.9.3 requires paragonie/random_compat ^1 | ^2 | 9.99.99 -> satisfiable by paragonie/random_compat[v9.99.99].
    - ramsey/uuid is locked to version 3.9.3 and an update of this package was not requested.

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\xampp\php\php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

И я уже пробовал команду `composer install --with-dependencies`, но и она не дала результата. Кстати, один пользователь из англоязычной аудитории говорит, что мне стоит сделать даунгрэйд PHP до версии 7.2, но и это мне тоже непонятно.

Comment: В OpenServer в настройках поменяйте версию php на требуемую и php.ini проверьте на наличие ext-mongodb установите, при необходимости.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сайт Вашего заказчика разрабатывался под PHP версии `^7.2`. Чтобы запустить его без ошибок, Вам требуется установить подходящую версию PHP. Версия 8 не обладает полной обратной совместимостью с версией 7, поэтому она не подходит.

Но Вы можете попробовать проигнорировать это требование:

```py
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Comment: Хорошо, но как сделать откат версии PHP? Можно ли это сделать командой или снова что-то вручную, как я устанавливал Composer?

Comment: @Endivine Откат выполнять не нужно. Можно установить несколько версий PHP. Как Вы установили PHP 8? Вы используете XAMPP?

Comment: Верно, я использую XAMPP. Мне нужно её переустановить с этой версией PHP? Я правильно понимаю?

Comment: @Endivine Да, это самый простой вариант. Но можно попробовать установить дополнительную версию в XAMPP. Сейчас постараюсь привести пример

Comment: Мне достаточно этого варианта, так как надобности сохранять свежую версию у меня нет. Огромнейшее вам спасибо!